# Graphic card which supports 1xUDH and 2xFull HD output

Tags: graphics-cards, 4k, uhd

I want to use multiple monitors for my PC, three in total.

I would like to know what graphics card would run:

- 1 x UHD (3840 x 2160) monitor
- 2 x Full HD (1920 x 1080) monitor

Which is the cheapest solution for this?

**Not for gaming**, using for work.

Comment: Do you do graphic intensive work, or are you just looking for a card that can support that much monitor real estate?

Comment: No, not for graphics things, only for excel tables, internet browsers, etc. So only can support 3 output but one with 4K.

Comment: I ran UHD + *one* hd + one lesser monitor on a gforce 660 in the past. You don't need much a

Comment: Could you include the interfaces that you may use to connect these monitors (VGA/DisplayPort/DVI-D/etc.) or the monitors' model numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the setup I have;
2 Dell 24" monitors
1 Samsung 49" tv (4:4:4 chroma)
This works out well because the TV has almost exactly double the diagonal measurement, meaning that windows dragged across have the same size on the 4K as they do on the side monitors. I really love the setup for work.

I'm using a Radeon RX470 and it works pretty good, mostly.
On occasion the screens will just kinda blink, and I don't know if that's because the video card is having trouble keeping up, or something else.

I'd really love to try a Geforce GTX 1070 for a week to see if it does the same thing.

One thing I'll say, it is really important to make sure that you have the right HDMI cable. We tried a '4K ready' Monster cable and it failed to show a picture. So we ordered one that can specifically handle 16GBps and that worked. It was also cheaper.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to HWR! Can you add a few more details about this graphics card please? Since the OP brought up price, can you add how much a new Radeon RX470 costs? Can you also tell us what ports the card has and which ones you are using for your setup. I see you are using an HDMI cable for the 4k, but what about the two 1080s?

Comment: @Cfinley Any RX470 should work. I have the Sapphire Radeon RX470 Turbo+. It has two display port, two hdmi. I'm using the display ports converted with a dongle to DVI for the side monitors, and HDMI for the main display, since this TV only has HDMI input available. Most of the RX470s I saw had similar ports, so that shouldn't be a problem. The only downside with Sapphire I've seen is that they don't have local US tech support, so everything has to be done online. I wish they had a phone number to call, but at least when I filled out the form they were quick to respond.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I would recommend you to rethink your Monitor Setup, UHD uses twice as many pixels in height than HD. If you move objects from one screen to another or just look from one to another, you will get serious headaches. I have this problem with a 1920x1200 main monitor and a 1280x720 second monitor.

On the other side, gaming or not, your setup will have a total resolution of 3840x3420. That means you will need something in the area of a GTX1070 or similar. This also means that you will have a good chance to find one with 3 Display Ports, which I also would recommend.

These cards that have 3 Display Ports and should do the job, if you want to be safe pick the GTX1070. If you want to try for a bargain, get a GTX1060. I can't recommend ATI, because I had some bad experiences with those.

Also, this is a shop link, because in this shop you can easily compare and look what else in on the market. You can select one and get them from somewhere else.

https://www.alternate.de/Hardware-Komponenten-Grafikkarten-PCIe-Karten-NVIDIA-GeForce-GTX-Gaming/html/listings/1346?lk=8406&sort=PRICE&order=ASC&showFilter=false&filter_2203=NVIDIA+GeForce+GTX+1070&filter_2203=NVIDIA+GeForce+GTX+1060&filter_2249=3.0#listingResult

Comment: Please make a recommendation for a graphics card, not just outline selection criteria. Thank you.